# PHP 7 vs 8 DateTime behavior with float timestamps

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

This example: https://onlinephp.io/c/3af93

```
<?php

new DateTime("@0.1");
```

throws an error in `PHP 7` but in `PHP 8` it will successfully parse the timestamp.

I am trying to understand why this behaves differently from the previous PHP version.
After looking through the PHP 7 vs 8 changelog, I could not find any direct reference to this behavior.

Is this an undocumented change or is this related to anything different?

Comment: I think it's a new undocumented feature.
It makes sense to also accept float timestamps.
The float value is not only accepted, but also processed correctly. https://3v4l.org/7Xbkv

Comment: [Request #79692 Creating DateTime from unixtime should support fractional seconds](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79692) - But it doesn't really explain when or how it was added.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, Documentation is same for PHP 7.* and PHP 8.*, Difference seems to be in echoing out Fatal error (Or Notices Or Warnings). They also need to echo out for PHP 8 as well.

If you refer to the documentation for [DateTime::__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php),

> **Note**:
> The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the
> $datetime parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
> specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

`